# Why is it called android:id, android:textAppearance, etc.?

Tags: android

Why does most of the XML attributes start with android:?
It seems like a great waste of typing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the XML namespace for all android related tags/attributes that you define in the root elements of your XML files. 
If you don't want to type that much, you can change

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to

```
 xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

This allows you to use elements in a way like

```
a:id=".."
```

Instead of *a* you can use any other name/letter combo too.

Comment: Note, though, that you can't make it the default namespace, at least last I tried (admittedly, probably 18 months ago...).

Comment: just to clarify, can you explain the point of it *in the context of android*? If we change the contents (schemas.android.com and/or "apk/res/android") will we break anything?

Comment: @PedroLoureiro This is not exclusively a android thing, but a general XML one. Each namespace URI is tied to a set of attribute names and tags. In this case `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` is tied to attributes like `layout_width`. If you remove parts of the URI or change it somehow, your app will break when using the file where you did that. You will get a `RuntimeException`, stating that attributes such as the mentioned `layout_width` could not be found. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) or [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) for more info.

Comment: I know about namespaces in xml. My question was more android related. If I change the "contents" of the namespace (xmlns:android="somethingelse") what would happen? I have the feeling that this isn't used for anything as when you use custom namespaces you can put in there whatever you want to (AFAIK!).

Comment: @PedroLoureiro No, you can't put any arbitrary character combination in there. As described at the end of my comment, you will get a RuntimeException. You can try that easily by setting up a new sample project and changing the URI in `res/layout/main.xml`. Once you execute the app it will crash immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This is the namespace defined by `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

Answer (score 0):

its about namespace. create your own custom view with custom attributes, and you'll see the difference.